Singular integral equations for beginners
I think I just got past the initial peak of the Dunning-Kruger plot with Singular Integral Equations applied to fracture mechanics (i.e., I realized I am lacking a lot of knowledge) and I thus would like to ask a couple of questions, hoping that others would be more skilled and be able to point me in the right direction. 
I am trying to solve the following system of singular integral equations:
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{G_1 (t)}{t-y} dt + \int_{-1}^{1} \sum_{j=1}^2 k_{1j}(y,t)G_j(t) dt = 2 \pi F_1 (y) $$
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{G_2 (t)}{t-y} dt + \int_{-1}^{1} \sum_{j=1}^2 k_{2j}(y,t)G_j(t) dt = 2 \pi F_2 (y)$$
Where:
$$ k_{11} = \int_0^{\infty} \left[\frac{2 \alpha^3}{K} (\frac{1}{m_1} - \frac{1}{m_2})\right] sin((t-y) \alpha) d \alpha $$
$$ k_{12} = \frac{1 - \nu}{\lambda^2 \lambda_2^2}\int_0^{\infty} \left[\frac{2 \alpha^3}{K} (\frac{p_1}{m_1} - \frac{p_2}{m_2}) + \frac{\lambda_2^4}{K} \alpha \kappa (r_1^2 + \alpha^2)(\frac{1}{m_1} - \frac{1}{m_2}) + 2 \alpha^2\right] sin((t-y) \alpha) d \alpha $$
$$ k_{21} = \frac{2}{\lambda^2 \lambda_2^2}\int_0^{\infty} \left[\frac{\lambda_2^4 \alpha}{K} \left(\frac{m_2^2 - \nu \alpha^2}{p_2m_2} - \frac{m_1^2 - \nu \alpha^2}{p_1m_1}\right) + \frac{\lambda_2^4}{K} \alpha \kappa (r_1^2 + \alpha^2)(\frac{1}{m_1} - \frac{1}{m_2}) + 2 \alpha^2\right] sin((t-y) \alpha) d \alpha $$
$$ k_{22} = \frac{1}{\lambda^4}\int_0^{\infty} \left[-\frac{2 \lambda_2^4(1-\nu)}{K} \left(\frac{m_1^2 - \nu \alpha^2}{p_1}\left( \frac{\alpha}{m_1 p_2} - \frac{\kappa(r_1^2 + \alpha^2}{2 \alpha m_1}\right) - \frac{m_2^2 - \nu \alpha^2}{p_2}\left(- \frac{\alpha}{m_2 p_1} + \frac{\kappa(r_1^2 + \alpha^2}{2 \alpha m_2}\right)\right) + 2 \kappa \alpha r_1 (1-\nu)^2 + (1 - \nu^2)\right] sin((t-y) \alpha) d \alpha $$
Where $\lambda_2, \kappa, \nu, \lambda, K \in \mathbb{R}$, $m_i^2 = p_i + \alpha^2$ and:
$$ p_1 = \frac{\kappa\lambda_2^4}{2} \left(1 + \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{\kappa^2 \lambda_2^2}}\right) $$
$$ p_2 = \frac{\kappa\lambda_2^4}{2} \left(1 - \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{\kappa^2 \lambda_2^2}}\right) $$
The problem is found in section 7 of this paper. I know how to discretize the system using Gauss-Chebyshev quadrature, however:

I am struggling with computing the $k_{ij}$ kernels. I realize this are Fourier sine transforms, however I am not sure on how to tackle the task
I have tried to compute a closed form solution for them, using the known properties like linearity, etc., however I end up not being able to compute this term (Inverse Fourier sine transform of product of two functions)
The paper is very outdated. Are there different, more modern techniques to tackle these problems? Thanks in advance

